# Is there a way in BigQuery to limit maximum amount of billed bytes (maximumBytesBilled) for all queries from specific service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cost-management

BigQuery provides an option to limit amount of billed bytes on query level as described here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#restrict-bytes-billed

Is there a way to set this limit on service account level, so it will be automatically applied to  all queries coming from particular service account.

I have also checked available quotas, but there is no relevant options here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

You can set a quota per day and per account. But you can't set for a specific (service) account or per query.

If you want to achieve that, you have to create a proxy/wrapper (with Cloud Run for example), that perform a dry run query and check the account and byte billed with your custom rules. If the rules are OK, the query can be ran